# Labelled satellite base map layer (not using Google Maps)

Tags: leaflet

I am having trouble recreating in Leaflet something that I found possible using the Google Maps API, which is having the base layer of my web map being geographically labeled satellite imagery. I can find "Street View" base imagery and I can find satellite imagery, but not with them combined into one base map layer.

Can anyone point me to an free resource for this kind of base map to use with Leaflet?

If what I am looking for does not exist, could my problem be solved by overlaying an existing "street view" map tile layer over the non-labelled satellite map tile layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapbox.com offers a basemap called "satellite streets". It looks like [this](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-satellite/).

You can sign up for free and include it into your leaflet map using your Map ID:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/MapID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks maRtin-- That's exactly what I am looking for. Mapbox gets promoted pretty hard on the Leaflet intro page, but it seemed I was able to do everything else I wanted without their services, so I didn't give Mapbox a further look. I'll remedy that.